# Сложный запрос к БД

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица '`country`' со списком стран

```
cid | title
```

и таблица '`places`' со списком экскурсий в странах

```
pid | country | title
```

где '`places.country`' = '`country.cid`'.

---

Вопрос в следующем. Как вывести одним запросом все `title` из '`country`', которые упоминаются в таблице '`places`'?
Не хочется разделять это на несколько запросов.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT DISTINCT c.title FROM country c JOIN places p ON p.country = c.cid;`

Comment: Ок. а как быть с таким запросом, где содержимое `p.country` совпадает с `c.cid`, но при этом `p.country` может равняться цепочке, обособленной несколькими тире, к примеру, `-14-15-16-`? Что-то вроде %-p.country-% LIKE c.cid

Comment: @NoName - Мне кажется, что вам надо почитать про нормализацию баз данных.

Comment: @ua6xh, спасибо, я уже нашла ответ.